# Inverse perspective transformation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project which attempts to correct the perspective distortion in a series of images.  I know that the correct way of doing this would be to calibrate the system with a known object and then compute the homography.  I created a virtual environment were I was able to do this (see images below).

[image]
[image]

However, I have run into a situation where the images that need to be corrected have already been collected and there is no way to reverse calibrate them (the images are relatively featureless).    Based on some additional data I am able to estimate the camera position.  With this information I thought that I should be able to create the homography matrix (H).  To do this wrote a program which creates a rotational matrix (R).  Multiplies R by a translational matrix (T) then by the camera intrinsics.  This matrix is then used in the WarpPerspective function.  The resulting images rotate the image with a fixed camera position.  I want to have the image in a fixed position and essentially rotate the camera.  How would I go about doing this?  My existing program is attached below.  Thank you for the help.

```
from numpy import *
import cv

global x
global y
global z
x = y = z = float(90)

def createMatrix(x, y, z):
    print x,y,z 

    x1 = (x-90) * (pi / 180)
    y1 = (y-90) * (pi / 180)
    z1 = (z-90) * (pi / 180)

    # Create a rotation matrix
    R_array = array([[x1], [y1], [z1]])
    R_Vec = cv.fromarray(R_array)
    R = cv.CreateMat(3, 3, cv.CV_64FC1)

    cv.Rodrigues2(R_Vec, R)
    R_r = array(R)
    R_r[0][2] = 0
    R_r[1][2] = 0
    R_r[2][2] = 1
    RR = cv.fromarray(R_r)

    #Create and combine with translation matrix
    Trans_Mat = array([[[1], [0], [-w/2]],
                        [[0], [1], [-h/2]],
                        [[0], [0], [1]]])

    Trans_Mat2 = cv.fromarray(Trans_Mat)
    R_T_Mat = dot(RR, Trans_Mat2)
    R_T_Mat[2][2] += h

    #Create and combine with camera matrix
    Intrinsic_Mat = array([[[h], [0], [w/2]],
                           [[0], [h], [h/2]],
                           [[0], [0], [1]]])

    Int_Mat = cv.fromarray(Intrinsic_Mat)
    H = dot(Int_Mat, R_T_Mat)
    return cv.fromarray(H)

def warp_displayImage():

    H2 = createMatrix(x,y,z)
    persp = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
    cv.WarpPerspective(im, persp, H2)

    cv.ShowImage("Distorted", im)
    cv.ShowImage("undistorted", persp)

def resetX(pos):
    global x
    x = float(pos)
    warp_displayImage()

def resetY(pos):
    global y
    y = float(pos)
    warp_displayImage()

def resetZ(pos):
    global z
    z = float(pos)
   warp_displayImage()

im = cv.LoadImage("homography_test.jpg")
h, w = cv.GetSize(im)
cv.NamedWindow("Distorted")
cv.NamedWindow("undistorted")
cv.CreateTrackbar("X axis", "undistorted", int(x),180, resetX)
cv.CreateTrackbar("Y axis", "undistorted", int(y),180, resetY)
cv.CreateTrackbar("Z axis", "undistorted", int(z),180, resetZ)


warp_displayImage()

cv.WaitKey(0)
cv.DestroyWindow("Distorted")
cv.DestroyWindow("undistorted")
```

This code is based on the help from Hammer:
[Perspective Warping in OpenCV based on know camera orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288473/perspective-warping-in-opencv-based-on-know-camera-orientation)

Comment: It is not clear, what is " I want to have the image in a fixed position and essentially rotate the camera.e". Do you want to show the same image independently on camera position or you want to interpolate views having just one given?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  I have an image taken from a given camera angle.  This is imposing a perspective distortion on the objects in that image.  What I would like to do is be able to manipulate that image as if I were looking straight down on the objects, this would remove the perspective distortion.  If the image was considered a flat plane.  Can I move the camera in 3D space to alter the view of that plane?

Comment: So, code you write here, already allows you to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately the code that I wrote does not quite work as I had hoped.  As I have stated, the code will rotate the image plane with respect to the camera.  Since the image is distorted then simply rotating it, without warping it, doesn't correct for it.  What I would like is for the image plane to remain fixed and the camera position to move.  Basically an inverse perspective transformation.